# What is 'eovdedn' doing in this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I ran across this code while doing some coding challenges and don't understand how it is working. I don't understand what the 'eovdedn' part is doing. The challenge was to return odd or even if the number was even or odd.

```
def isEvenOrOdd(num):
    return 'eovdedn'[num % 2::2]
```

My solution was:

```
def isEvenOrOdd(num):
    return "even" if num%2==0 else "odd"
```

Comment: NEVER do this if there's a remote possibility someone else (which includes future you) needs to read your code. "Shortest code" challenges are good for demonstrating a good understanding of language features, but readability and clarity are much much much more valuable in real life

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Which one my solution or the other one?

Comment: My previous comment was talking about the other solution. Your solution is much better. If you _really_ wanted to shorten your code, you could flip the condition and do `return "odd" if num%2 else "even"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num %2` returns `False` or `True`, which can be understood as 0 or 1.

Using the slicing notation 'eovdedn'[num % 2::2] we can have the following results:

- If num % 2 equals False (0) : 
  `'eovdedn'[0::2]` = even (returns every 2 characters starting from 0)
- If num % 2 equals True (1) : 
  `'eovdedn'[1::2]` = odd (returns every 2 characters starting from 1)

Answer (score 2):

```
'eovdedn'[num % 2::2]
```

That is the syntax for a *slice*.

`num % 2` starts the slice at position 0 or 1 depending if the number is even or odd, and `::2` includes every second character thereafter.

So if the number is even you get `e-v-e-n`, and if the number is odd you get `-o-d-d` (without the hyphens).